# Writing into text file using Arduino and processing IDE

Tags: file-io, arduino, processing, processing-ide

My work is to write a value which will be sent by arduino to processing IDE and processing IDE must write it into a specified text file. 
I used [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181839/arduino-how-to-get-serial-data-without-ide) as reference and tried a code. But, nothing is written into the specified file.
Can anyone suggest me some solution?

Answer (score 0):

First off: no you don't. The Processing IDE doesn't do anything, a processing program you write will listen and write. The PDE is just a glorified text editor =)

That said, if you can get your signal into your plain processing application, then you can write that data to a file using the standard file writing functions, see http://processing.org/reference/createWriter_.html for these.

If you can't get your data into your processing application, that's a very different problem, and there are a number of SO questions that already cover this topic (you will find them with a normal search).

Comment: Yes I accept your point. I want to do the same thing which you have mentioned in your comment. Processing must get the signal from Arduino and write it into a specified file. Please suggest me a way to complete this process

Comment: I did. The writing process is literally following the instructions from the processing documentation, for getting the signal from your arduino into your processing application, http://playground.arduino.cc/interfacing/processing