# how to read arduino serial monitor data from visual studio and save as an array

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, arduino-uno

Im getting following data on arduino serial monitor. I want to read those data from visual studio and save as an array. Please anybody help me. It will be a big help to me. Please

Arduino serial monitor

[image]

Comment: You should look in this direction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181839/arduino-how-to-get-serial-data-without-ide

Comment: definitely let us know if you are working with console, winforms, WPF, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume winforms.  If not, then this wont be helpful.

First, add a serial port to your form from the toolbox. Then do something like this to get the data into an array:

```
            string tempStr;
            int size = serialPort1.BytesToRead;
            //runs as long as there are bytes in the serial buffer to be read,
            //you may need to change the way it runs to get all of your data depending upon
            //how the device is sending data to the serial port
            while (size != 0)
            {
                //store incoming byte
                int b1 = serialPort1.ReadByte();
                //converts byte to character
                char c = Convert.ToChar(b1);
                //puts the character into a string                
                tempStr = c.ToString();
                //append it to Rx (output string)
                Rx += tempStr;
            }
            //you'll may need to do some messing around with the character you use to split
            string[] results = Rx.Split(new Char[] {'\r' });
```